# How to catch the exception from C++ in python via pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am making code in python using pybind11.

For example, I have test1.cpp, test_pybind.cpp and example.py

heaan_pybind.cpp

```
namespace py=pybind11;
PYBIND11_MODULE(test, m)
{
  py::class_<test1>(m, "test1")
  .def("fn", ...)
}
```

And in example.py, I want to control the exception like below.

```
import test
while True:
  try:
    test.test1.fn(...)
  except ???:
    print("exception error.")
```

How can I catch the error or exception from test.cpp in example.py ?

Answer (score 11):

The trivial way is to just make sure all the c++ exceptions you want to catch in python are also part of your bind.

So in your module, assuming you have a cpp exception type called `CppExp` you would do something like

```
namespace py=pybind11;
PYBIND11_MODULE(test, m)
{
  py::register_exception<CppExp>(module, "PyExp");
}
```

that will create a new python exception called `PyExp` and it will cause any code that throws `CppExp` to remap it into the python exception.

Then in your python code you can do

```
import test
while True:
  try:
    test.test1.fn(...)
  except test.PyExp as ex:
    print("exception error.", ex)
```

additional pybind11 docs on exception handling are here:
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/exceptions.html

If your c++ exception has custom fields or methods that you want to translate into python, you will have to actually modify the pybind11 code as per my answer here:
[How can you bind exceptions with custom fields and constructors in pybind11 and still have them function as python exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087383/how-can-you-bind-exceptions-with-custom-fields-and-constructors-in-pybind11-and/62087976#62087976)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the type of exception, simply you can catch the most general type such as `Exception`. See below

```
import test
while True:
  try:
    test.test1.fn(...)
  except Exception:
    print("exception error.")
```